# Отправить сообщение пользователю через VK API из приложения с типом "Веб-сайт"

Tags: vkontakte-api

Есть сайт с уже работающей авторизацией.
Для сайта в VK создали приложение с типом веб-сайт.
Есть необходимость добавить возможность сайту от имени приложения отправлять сообщение пользователям через `VK API`.
Возможно ли подобное? Насколько я понял, для приложений типа "сайт" доступны не все методы.
Если возможно, то какой метод будет правильнее использовать?

Answer (score 6):

На сегодня есть следующие варианты отправки сообщения пользователю ВК:

1. от другого пользователя ВК [`messages.send()`](https://new.vk.com/dev/messages.send);
2. от сообщества в ответ на запрос пользователя – [Сообщения для бизнеса](https://new.vk.com/dev/bizmessages);
3. уведомления от приложения [`secure.sendNotification()`](https://new.vk.com/dev/secure.sendNotification);
4. платная отправка SMS [`secure.sendSMSNotification()`](https://new.vk.com/dev/secure.sendSMSNotification).

Варианты 1–3 не доступны приложению типа «Сайт». Но можно поступить так:

Заведите аккаунт пользователя ВКонтакте, представляющий ваш сайт – вымышленный персонаж, директор, «лицо» сайта.

Создайте приложение типа Standalone, и получите для него бессрочный токен с правами messages. Тут придётся всего один раз выполнить процедуру с копированием токена из адресной строки браузера.

Зато теперь у вас есть токен, с которым вы сможете из скриптов сайта писать личные сообщения пользователям. Приходить они будут от имени того аккаунта.

Скорее всего, пользователи будут что-то писать в ответ – обрабатывайте их ответы.

Наладьте какой-то механизм на случай если токен вдруг перестанет работать – чтобы вы тут же узнали и выпустили новый.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно для такого получить `access_token` вручную, иначе не будет у него нужных прав. Для этого перейти по ссылке:
`http://oauth.vk.com/oauth/authorize?redirect_uri=http://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&response_type=token&client_id={app_id}&scope=friends,messages,offline`

В строке адреса скопировать `access_token` и использовать его для отправки сообщений:

`https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/messages.send?user_id={receiver_vk_id}&message={vk_msg}&title={vk_msg_title}&access_token={received_access_token}`

P.S. Параметр offline дает токену неограниченное время существования.

Comment: правильно ли я понял что access_token должен должен копировать каждый пользователь после авторизации?

Comment: если указать другой redirect_uri то не будет нужных прав. Мной делалось это не для использования пользователем и для моих целей вполне подходило. Но по сути вы поняли правильно.

Comment: И еще одно, сообщение можно отсылать от другого пользователя, никак не от приложения. Это ведь не публикация на стену группы.

Comment: Вряд ли юзер, который так трясется за свои данные будет копировать что-то из строки браузера и вставлять это еще куда-то для авторизации... Это выглядит подозрительно......а если учесть еще что юзер ленивый - то тем более что-то там куда-то копипастить просто влом будет)

Comment: Врядли юзер захочет что б от его имени кто-то отсылал личные сообщения

Comment: Так речи и нет о том, чтоб от имени юзера что-то отсылать)

Comment: Вы можете отсылать как я выше писал только от пользователя. Что бы от своего какого-нибудь аккаунта отсылать я вам объяснил как. Зачем вам авторизовывать для этого вообще юзера? Соберите айдишники пользователей и со своего делайте рассылку как я описал выше.

Comment: Как вы вообще представляете себе отправку сообщения от имени группы? Вам хоть раз в вк приходило сообщение от группы? Или вы находили как группа может общаться с пользователями в самом вк?

Comment: @alias вы хоть видите кто вопрос задавал и кто с вами разговаривает?))  Отсылать можно хоть через сам контакт.... но как, по вашему сам пользователь должен получать сообщения? без таких хакерских приемчиков а-ля скопировать токен из урла и вставить в куда-то чтоб пройти авторизацию - пользователь ничего не получит.....ибо для этого нужен метод `messages.get`..а юзер так делать не будет.....а других доступных способов пользователю получать сообщения через апи нет (т.к. сайт, а это не `standalone`)

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский могу отправить сообщение по этому алгоритму. Я его успешно использую для отсылки уведомлений с сайта администраторам. Хотя про `standalone` думаю вы правы, так как приложение у меня с этим типом.

Comment: @alias  еще раз.......вы отправите, а пользователь как получит? Если не заставлять пользователя авторизовываться вот таким костыльным способом?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский пользователь получит его в личные сообщения внутри вк

Comment: @alias  ммм. возможно я сам вопрос недопонял.....мне казалось что юзеры тоже будут через этот самый сайт сидеть, а не через вк......надо у ТС уточнить