# Запросить права доступа при авторизации

Tags: vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте!

Имеется скрипт (standalone-приложение):

```
VK.init({
     apiId:ID_ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ
});

function auth(userid){
    alert(userid.status);
    if(userid.status=='connected'){
        if(typeof(userid.session.user) == 'undefined'){
                VK.Api.call('users.get', {uid: userid.session.mid},
                function(){
                    $('#vk').append('Ваш ID: '+userid.session.mid);
                });
            }
        else{
            $('#vk').append('Ваш ID: '+userid.session.mid);
        }
    }
    else{
        VK.Auth.login(auth, ПРАВА_ДОСТУПА);
    }
}

    VK.Auth.getLoginStatus(auth);
```

Необходимо получить разрешение на отправку личных сообщений. Если я делаю так:

```
VK.Auth.login(auth, VK.access.FRIENDS);
```

то popup сообщает, что приложение хочет получить доступ к списку друзей. А вот:

```
VK.Auth.login(auth, VK.access.MESSAGES);
```

does not work.

Прошу подсказать, в чем дело.

P.S. Права доступа приложения https://vk.com/dev/permissions. OpenAPI https://vk.com/dev/openapi

P.P.S. На данный момент нашел такое решение [Отправить сообщение пользователю через VK API из приложения с типом "Веб-сайт"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517649/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-vk-api-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82), а именно:

> Заведите аккаунт пользователя ВКонтакте, представляющий ваш сайт –
>   вымышленный персонаж, директор, «лицо» сайта.
>
> Создайте приложение типа Standalone, и получите для него бессрочный
>   токен с правами messages. Тут придётся всего один раз выполнить
>   процедуру с копированием токена из адресной строки браузера.
>
> Зато теперь у вас есть токен, с которым вы сможете из скриптов сайта
>   писать личные сообщения пользователям. Приходить они будут от имени
>   того аккаунта.
>
> Скорее всего, пользователи будут что-то писать в ответ – обрабатывайте
>   их ответы.
>
> Наладьте какой-то механизм на случай если токен вдруг перестанет
>   работать – чтобы вы тут же узнали и выпустили новый.